# How do you filtered subelements based on class name

Tags: javascript

I have an image slider with some product images: every product con have different pics that could be identified by the class (DeepFaceMashie,McDowall, Niblick in the example) of the unordered list element.

```
<div class="cd-slider-wrapper">
    <ul class="cd-slider">                          
        <li class="selected DeepFaceMashie"><img src="img/deepface.jpeg"></li>
        <li class="DeepFaceMashie"><img src="img/deepface2.jpeg"></li>
        <li class="DeepFaceMashie"><img src="img/deepface3.jpeg"></li>
        <li class="McDowall"><img src="img/mcdowall.jpeg"></li>
        <li class="McDowall"><img src="img/mcdowall2.jpeg"></li>
        <li class="McDowall"><img src="img/mcdowall3.jpeg"></li>
        <li class="Niblick"><img src="img/niblick.jpeg"></li>
        <li class="Niblick"><img src="img/niblick2.jpeg"></li>
    </ul>                       
</div>
```

Via javascript I can get all elements of the unordered list

```
sliderContainer = navigation.parents('.cd-slider-wrapper').find('.cd-slider')
```

At this point, how can I create a copy of sliderContainer, containing only one product images?
I could extract only the children elements, but I need to mantain slideerContainer structure, only with selected elements in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you want a copy of that slider just with a specific type of products which you select via classname!?
If so, you can clone this slider and insert it's copy next to it or an specific element of your choise. Next thing you have to do is to remove unnecessary elements:

```
$( ".cd-slider" ).clone().appendTo(".cd-slider-wrapper").contents().not('.McDowall').remove();
```

[working example for slider clone with specific content](https://jsfiddle.net/f990o57v/3/)